# SendInBlue API .NET6 Core Razor Pages in C# AddContactToList catching and throwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages, sendinblue

I a using the exact code here https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference/addcontacttolist-1 to add a user to a list. It all works, user is created/updated (if exists) then the user is added to the list. However, when adding to the list it throws an error.

> Error calling AddContactToList:
> {"code":"invalid_parameter","message":"Contact already in list and/or
> does not exist"}

[image]

Their code shows a display result in JSON which will never get hit because it throws at the Add method.

Answer (score 3):

The error is straight-forward. The contact is already in the list and the API enforces uniqueness.

You can get the contacts that are already in the list via `getContactsFromList`

https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference/getcontactsfromlist

or contact details via `getContactInfo`:

https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference/getcontactinfo-1

So, you will need to check whether the contact is already in the list. If so, then **don't add it**. Otherwise, you can add it without problems.

Comment: Ok, was trying not to get the list and hoping for a valid error to present. Guess I will ignore that one.

Comment: @Zippy you can decide to not handle this error, but you will need to make sure that in your `catch` clause you handle other errors, so, it is advisable to change `Exception e` to have a more specific type, so other exceptions will not be ignored.